# Ошибка в "Последние входящие сообщения"

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, выборы, уведомления

На странице [2015 Выборы модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1?tab=nomination) я оставил комментарий. Сегодня получаю уведомление о том, что мне написали ответ -- видно на скриншоте.
Но ссылка битая.
[Ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1#comment-542562) не открывается. Почему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ответ (и как оказалось - не один) виден на странице.
На скриншоте - это второй и третий комментарии.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кстати, можно принять ответ, он вроде бы объясняет суть происходящего.

Comment: а тут баги исправляют? если отметить как ответ, не получится ли так, что не исправят?

Comment: Nicolas передаст этот баг в общий трекер. Но если честно, я сомневаюсь, что его исправят в ближайшее время. )

Comment: а Nicolas это кто?

Comment: [Nicolas Chabanovski](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6/nicolas-chabanovsky), сотрудник StackOverflow, менеджер сообщества, когда-то основал сайт Хэшкод, который потом был куплен SO и стал ru.SO.

Comment: Кстати, с вас ответ вот сюда: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2101/181472

Answer (score 10):

Ссылки перестают работать:

- когда включается paging в комментариях к кандидатуре - потому что комментарий при заходе на страницу не виден (сам намучался)
- когда по умолчанию активен второй таб на странице (ссылка не переключает на таб с кандидатурой)

Comment: я оставил новый комментарий на странице “Последние входящие сообщения”. у вас работает ссылка на него из "Последние входящие сообщения”?

Comment: @Stack нет. причем я каждый раз на это напарываюсь, тыкаюсь по странице, и только через пару секунд доходит. и вот опять... :(